# Flask PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to run a Flask application using `/opt/mount1/python35/bin/python3.5 notification.py` and I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
 * Serving Flask app "notification" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notification.py", line 19, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 247, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/mount1/python35/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1289, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

> I have given recursive 777 permission to the flask application folder.

From the above stack trace, I am not sure what is going wrong.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

---

***Updates***

I tried to run the Flask app using the **core python of CentOS 7.6 i.e Python 2.7** and it **worked!!**

I am not sure why it is **not working for a python version 3.5.6** which has been installed from its RPM to the path `/opt/mount1/python35`.

Comment: I think it is a python installation issue. Your preinstalled python2.7 has the access to the site-packages but 3.5 does not as it is installed explicitly at an outer location. If you are not already using proper virtualenv to handle the installation please do. You can refer this link https://binaykumarray.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/python-2-python-3-or-both/ and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had installed the Python 3.5 separately in a different path, I had to place the following **shebang** at the top of my file to fix the issue:

```
#!/opt/mount1/python35/bin/python3.5
```

Answer (score 8):

Error 13 (your permissions error) is usually resolved by changing your port number.  TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are registered or 'privileged' port numbers - users are not allowed to run servers on them. My guess from the first warning message shown (regarding the server in a production environment) is that you are running your application on a low port number (probably 80), but you if you run it on a different port number, say 4000 or something (over 1024), you will avoid this error.

You may find [this link](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) helpful

excerpt:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
```

Comment: As you can find in the stack trace: `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/` .. isn't it running on port **5000** ?

Comment: It should, then it could mean that an application is already running on port 5000.

Comment: @Reese No, I do not see any other services running at port 5000

Comment: Check with this command "netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN" to be sure, then try with another port if you get the same error "app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=some_thing_higher)" The error Errno 13 means that Flask is not able to bind.

Comment: @Reese tried also changing to `app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8050)` .. still getting same error

Comment: I tried to run the Flask app using the core python library of CentOS 7.6 i.e Python 2.7 and it worked!! Not sure why it is not working for a pythong version 3.5.6 which has been installed from its RPM in `/opt/mount1/python35` path