# Flask and EC2: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to deploy my Flask app on AWS's EC2 and have been following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-python-web-app-on-aws-57ed772b2319) but my console has been throwing me this error:

```
[ec2-user@ip- flask_test]$ python3 main.py
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=80)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1010, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 963, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 806, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 699, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 470, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831060/flask-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied) that port 80 could be a privileged port, but on EC2, I specified inbound traffic to port 80 like so in the tutorial:
[image]

I have also attempted using `sudo python3 main.py` but it throws me another `ImportError: No module named flask` error instead. What am I missing?

Comment: this has nothing to do with AWS. you installed flask for the user, not super user. you should anyhow use nginx or similar to reverse proxy requests to port 80 to your local flask port

Comment: did you manage to solve? I have the same issue using elasticbeanstalk

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem can be resolved by running `pip install` with sudo. You currently appear to have installed the packages for your user not the super user.

Now, you would be best as well to not do that, and rather set up a reverse proxy using nginx, whereby any requests to `xx.xx.xx.xx/flask` (on port 80) are redirected to `localhost:5000` or however you are running it. You can google this last step and find out how to do it, it is rather straight forward.